# Staying put on a frame label

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to use buttons to jump to frame labels. They jump to the label just fine, but they won't stop when pressed again. Below is the code I am using to have the button rest when pressed again.

```
getting_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gettingStarted);

function gettingStarted(evt:MouseEvent):void {
gotoAndPlay("ipad_in");
if (this.currentLabel == "ipad_rest"){
this.gotoAndStop("ipad_rest");
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure i understand what you are trying to do. On first click you want it to go to frame labeled "ipad_in" and on second click if it is already on frame "ipad_in" then go to frame "ipad_rest". Is that the results you are looking for?

Comment: Yea, I got it figured out.

Duh have to flip flop them so it checks label first and then goes to correct frame label.

function gettingStarted(evt:MouseEvent):void 
{
   if (this.currentLabel == "ipad_rest")
      this.gotoAndStop("ipad_rest");
   else
      gotoAndPlay("ipad_in");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh have to flip flop them so it checks label first and then goes to desired frame label.

```
function gettingStarted(evt:MouseEvent):void 
{
   if (this.currentLabel == "ipad_rest")
      this.gotoAndStop("ipad_rest");
   else
      gotoAndPlay("ipad_in");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the following line you are testing the frame name for "ipad_rest" but on the line before you set the frame to "ipad_in" so in effect the currentLabel will never be "ipad_rest"

```
gotoAndPlay("ipad_in");
if (this.currentLabel == "ipad_rest"){// will never be true
```

Not tested but this should be about what you want it all depends on if "ipad_in" is still the active frame . You were vague on your description.

```
function gettingStarted(evt:MouseEvent):void {
  if (this.currentLabel == "ipad_in"){
    this.gotoAndStop("ipad_rest");
  }else{
    gotoAndPlay("ipad_in");
  }
}
```